# Removing a user from the "Everyone Except External User" group in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, office-365

I have a new account in Office 365, but I need to remove its access to the tenant's SharePoint Online sites.  I have already removed the SharePoint Online (Plan 1) feature from the license associated with the account, but this hasn't succeeded in removing the account's access.

A handful of the sites have the "Everyone Except External Users" group listed with some level of permission.  That new account is able to access those sites from this group's access permissions, even though that account is no longer licensed for SharePoint Online.  I'm wondering if there is a way to remove this account from the "Everyone Except External Users" group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Everyone except external' is a group built into the SharePoint codebase. You cannot modify membership as it doesn't actually have membership (and again, being part of the codebase rather than a modifiable object).

You could use Conditional Access Policies to control what the account can long into. As you've observed, removing the SPO license doesn't remove their access to SPO.

Comment: As part of the testing, we unlicensed the account.  Even unlicensed an internal user can access a SharePoint Online site from the permissions granted by that "Everyone Except External" group (including the files saved in the document library).

I'll give the Conditional Access Policies a try to see if that fixes it.

Comment: Yes, an unlicensed user does not remove access to SPO. It just means you're violating the license if that user uses SPO.

Comment: Sadly, to set up and use Condition Access Policies in Office 365 for SharePoint, our Azure AD requires a premium P1 or P2 license.

Comment: That is correct. That is the only Microsoft-provided method you're going to accomplish what you're asking to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PowerShell to remove the External user completely .

```
Import-Module Microsoft.Online.Sharepoint.PowerShell -DisableNameChecking
$AdminSiteURL="SharePoint Tenant Admin URL"
$Cred = Get-Credential
Connect-SPOService -URL $AdminSiteURL -Credential $Cred
$ExternalUserID = "UserEmail.com"
$ExternalUser = Get-SPOExternalUser -SiteUrl -filter $ExternalUserID
Remove-SPOExternalUser -UniqueIDs @($ExternalUser.UniqueId) -Confirm:$falses
```

Comment: Helpful, but the issue is that the user is internal.  Is there an option for this?